# bootstrap twitter datepicker + modal - calendar coming up in parent screen instead of modal screen

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I have a form (`Payment.php`) which I am displaying in a modal screen using twitter bootstrap. 
In the form I have a date field for which I found [this](http://www.eyecon.ro/bootstrap-datepicker/) bootstrap plugin.

But the problem is the calendar is loaded in the parent screen (`Index.php`) and not on the modal form where it is actually required.

Can anyone suggest a solution to this.

Following is the code that I have tried.

Imports:

```
<link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/datepicker.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.8.0.js"></script>
```

PHP:

```
<div class="controls">
        <input data-datepicker="datepicker" class="span3" value="2012-09-13" data-date-format="yyyy-mm-dd" id="dp2" >
        </div>
```

JS:

```
$('#dp2').datepicker();
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Add z-index to .datepicker class and make more than .modal

```
.datepicker {
z-index: 9999;
top: 0;
left: 0;
padding: 4px;
margin-top: 1px;
-webkit-border-radius: 4px;
-moz-border-radius: 4px;
border-radius: 4px;
}
```

Comment: unfortunately not working for me (bootstrap 2.3, jquery 1.8.3, jquery ui 1.10.1, Firefox 20pre on OS X). In Chrome it works.

Comment: Doesn't work for me either, it shows the date picker in the top left of the window rather than below the textbox.

Comment: The answer is old, if does not work for you that means something has changed or there is some conflict in css. If it does't work for you that does not mean you will downvote it.

Answer (score 8):

After several tests, I can confirm again my comment to the answer of @m4k: The z-index solution via CSS file does not work on Firefox 19 and 20 on OS X. Chrome works though. I did not further test it on other browsers or OS.

The solution which works for me, is to set the z-index via jquery-ui's datepicker config as shown below:

```
$('#datepicker').datepicker({ 
    beforeShow: function() { $('#datepicker').css("z-index", 1051); }
});
```

where the z-index should be higher as the one of the modal (in bootstrap 2.3, the modal has 1050).

A even more advanced solution could be to call a method in `beforeShow` that determines the currently highest z-index on the page automatically. On http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2009/Sep/12/jQuery-UI-Datepicker-and-zIndex you find an example.

---

**Update:** Automatically set the z-index 1 higher than the modal

Easy sample how to determine what the z-index is of the underlying modal:

```
$("#datepicker").closest(".modal").css("z-index")
```

Thus, the `beforeShow` method becomes

```
$('#datepicker').datepicker({ 
    beforeShow: function() { 
      var $datePicker = $("#datepicker");
      var zIndexModal = $datePicker.closest(".modal").css("z-index");
      $datePicker.css("z-index", zIndexModal + 1); 
    }
});
```

Answer (score 4):

..none of this worked for me. 
I'm running bootstrap 2.3.2, and no matter how I try via javascript, bootstrap's javascript  will always reset the datepicker's z-index back to (in my case) 21.
Sure, there's a way to do it in javascript, but I find the css way quite clean.

So, this did the trick:

```
/* otherwise datepickers won't show in a modal dialog */
.datepicker {
    z-index:1051 !important;
}
```

Comment: This worked for me but I had to use .ui-datepicker.  .datepicker isn't the class name in my case (not sure why)?

Comment: @JasonCoder probably you are using jquery ui's datepicker, not bootstrap's

Comment: @Davide right you are!  Nothing like having 4 or 5 datepickers in a codebase ;)

Answer (score 0):

I followed the beforeShow approach, but had to get the closest modal from the input for the z-index calculation, and then make sure to set the z-index on the separate div that is the calendar.

```
var DEFAULT_Z_INDEX = 10;

$('#my-date-input')
    .datepicker()
    .on('show', function() {

        // Make sure that z-index is above any open modal.
        var $input= $(this);
        var modalZIndex = $input.closest('.modal').css('z-index');
        var zIndex = DEFAULT_Z_INDEX;
        if (modalZIndex) {
            zIndex = parseInt(modalZIndex) + 1;
        }

        $('.datepicker').css("z-index", zIndex);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

html

```
 <!-- Text input-->
<div class="form-group"> 
    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="textinput">Date TO</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <input   type="text" id="DateToP"  name="DateToP" placeholder="Post Code" class="form-control datepicker">
    </div> 
</div>
```

css

```
<style type="text/css">
 .datepicker {
    z-index:1051 !important;
  }
</style>
```

jquery

```
   $('#DateToP').datepicker({
       format: 'yyyy-mm-dd',
      autoclose: true
  });
```

Answer (score -1):

I used a display: none; attribute to the CSS file for .datepicker. And that worked fine.