# Datepicker in modal issue

Tags: javascript, datepicker, modal-dialog, z-index, bootstrap-datepicker

I am trying to use [this datepicker](http://eternicode.github.io/bootstrap-datepicker/)
in combination with a modal from bootstrap.
Unfortunately, the datepicker turns out to show on a really weird spot:
[click here for image.](https://gyazo.com/855a7ad8b8db3a51057a7c75f8c72938)

I've tried many things, also the suggestions at [this post.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12413070/bootstrap-twitter-datepicker-modal-calendar-coming-up-in-parent-screen-inste) But unfortunately nothing seems to work, z-index, several css adjustments, nothing.

I am hoping that someone knows the answer. This are the snippets of my code:

**Javascript:**

```
$(document).on("click", ".request", function () {
    var date = $(this).data('id');

    $('#dateRequestSelect').datepicker({
        format: "dd-mm-yyyy",
        startDate: "12-1-2016",
        language: "nl",
        multidate: 2,
        multidateSeparator: " tot ",
        daysOfWeekDisabled: "0,6",
        parentEl: '#day-request'
    });
});
```

**The Modal caller:**

```
<td width="3.2%" class="block workday">
    <a class="request" data-id="'.$displayer.'" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#day-request">
        <div style="height:100%;width:100%;">
        </div>
    </a>
</td>
```

**The Modal**

```
<!-- Modal for requesting -->
<div class="modal fade" id="day-request" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel"><strong>Verlof aanvragen</strong></h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        Datum: <input type="text" id="dateRequestSelect">
        <div id="modalRequestBody"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Sluiten</button>
        <!--<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>-->
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- End of Modal -->
```

The CSS of the datepicker is the same as the one from the download, the same goes for the bootstrap one.

Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this. The way of doing so:

**Add to the javascript:**

```
container: '#pickdate-container'
```

**Add a div (for me pickdate-container) to the modal, at the spot you want the date picker to be at:**

```
<div id="pickdate-container"> 
            </div>
```

This solved the issue for me!